# Bigtable: mutating multiple values into single column in a single column family

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I've tried to insert 100 values into a column `test_col` in column family `test_cf` in a row key `test-123`

The problem is that I successfully inserted 100 values into Bigtable.

However, The number of values in the `test_col` column in `test_cf` is less than 100 and It appears to be randomly inserted.

The code I wrote is below.

```
rows = []
values = ['123-123124-325324', '543-123-45324-123123', '292-123124-54324-234', '292-213123-123123123-3213']
 # ...  100 values in the list

row_key = 'test-123'.encode()
direct_row = table.direct_row(row_key)
for val in values:
    row.set_cell("test_cf",
                 "test_col".encode('utf-8'),
                 val,
                 datetime.utcnow())
     
    rows.append(row)

rtn = table.mutate_rows(rows)

for i, status in enumerate(rtn):
    if status.code != 0:
        print('ERROR')
```

And the weird thing is that the response status is always 0 for the 100 values mutation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is not doing what you intended. Each `set_cell` call is writing to the same row ("test-123"), the same column family ("test_cf") and the same column qualifier ("test_col"). The value is different each time, but the timestamp associated with each value is the current time which could be the same across multiple `set_cell`s. Because a single cell in Bigtable is indexed by the (row, family, column, timestamp) tuple, this code can overwrite data it wrote earlier in the loop.

So, it is entirely possible that the first 3 `set_cell`s look like this:

```
row:       "test-123"
family:    "test_cf"
column:    "test_col"
value:     "123-123124-325324"
timestamp: t0

row:       "test-123"
family:    "test_cf"
column:    "test_col"
value:     "543-123-45324-123123"
timestamp: t0

row:       "test-123"
family:    "test_cf"
column:    "test_col"
value:     "292-123124-54324-234"
timestamp: t1
```

In this case the second entry overwrites the first, as (row, family, column, timestamp) is identical.

The status code will be `0` for successful calls, so that is working as expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot for letting me know the structure of the indexing of Bigtable. I will try another way to insert the values with same column qualifier.

Comment: Sure thing. Two suggestions: Use a counter instead of an actual time as the timestamp, or keep track of the last timestamp you set and if the new one is the same or smaller then increment it by 1 microsecond.

Comment: That's good suggestions! I choose to increment it by 1 microsecond to insert a cell while avoiding the problem. Thanks!